# Record types: overriding EqualityContract breaks the equality/hashcode match

Tags: c#, .net-5, c#-9.0

Newly introduced record types allow to override `EqualityContract` for type which makes possible to create a situation when two objects are equal but have different hashcodes which opposes [guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gethashcode?view=net-5.0) for `GetHashCode` overriding:

> If you override the GetHashCode method, you should also override Equals, and vice versa. If your overridden Equals method returns true when two objects are tested for equality, your overridden GetHashCode method must return the same value for the two objects.

```
    public record Base(string Foo);

    public record Child(string Foo, string Bar) : Base(Foo)
    {
        protected override Type EqualityContract => typeof(Base);
    }

    var b = new Base("Foo");
    var c = new Child("Foo", "Bar");
    Console.WriteLine(b == c); // True
    Console.WriteLine(b.GetHashCode() == c.GetHashCode()); // False
```

While removing the extra property from `Child` makes `GetHashCode` and `Equals` "match".

Obviously this can be fixed with overriding `GetHashCode`, but I wonder why overriding `EqualityContract` does not automatically lead to  having `GetHashCode` return value "matching" `Equals` implementation? Or is there any other way to handle that except manual `GetHashCode` override?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see in [equality members part of records proposal](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/csharp-9.0/records.md#equality-members),

> `GetHashCode()` returns an `int` result of a deterministic function
> combining the following values:
>
> - For each instance field `fieldN` in the record type that is not inherited, the value of
>   `System.Collections.Generic.EqualityComparer<TN>.Default.GetHashCode(fieldN)`
>   where TN is the field type, and
> - If there is a base record type, the value of base.GetHashCode(); otherwise the value of
>   `System.Collections.Generic.EqualityComparer<System.Type>.Default.GetHashCode(EqualityContract)`.

So, in your example `GetHashCode` for `Base` will be

```cs
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return EqualityComparer<Type>.Default.GetHashCode(EqualityContract) + EqualityComparer<string>.Default.GetHashCode(Foo);
}
```

And for the `Child`

```cs
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return base.GetHashCode() + EqualityComparer<string>.Default.GetHashCode(Bar);
}
```

For the inherited record the `EqualityContract` isn't used for hash code calculation. If an extra property `Bar` is removed, the value from `Base` is used and you'll get a hash values equality. So, overriding of `GetHashCode` is needed.

This behavior is also observed using [sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwD4AEBMBGAsAKFygZgAIE4BjAewQBMiAhaOAChQwAYiAxCigSgG5cuIiKKES5KrQDCACwCWAG2ot2XHgBoxahgl5EQ9Rk259hogN7nRogA4IK8MvFoUAbogTzqcIgBUAT1tfAFEARwBXCEV5GADpCgA7GAQIZyIAXgA+IjjgigAzJgYoOAFrIgBfIRxEiDA4KFs031YAOgAlCOT5BraEsFslRABlRDd5MkbcKxwbcXQiAEkoEIAPeAQ6xSXE2ItqnEqgA)

Comment: Thank you. I figured the same (except finding the proposal). Still (though it does not match SO guidelines =)  I wonder why =))